# How to Open Files in Directories with Spaces using CMD as Admin?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, admin

I'm writing a script to automate software installation and optimization using batch files. It needs administrator privileges.

When admin rights are given to `cmd`, I had to switch from `"%cd%\program.exe"` to `"%0\..\program.exe"`. However, after doing that, I can't get a file to open if it is in a directory with spaces.

Subsequently, I removed the quotation marks at the beginning like this:

`%0\..\program.exe"`

This caused the directory problem to go away but now Programs with spaces won't open and using `xcopy` will give me a parse error.

I need it to open both files with spaces and files inside of directories with spaces.

Please help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%0` should already be doublequoted, but is the `d`rive `p`ath `n`ame and e`x`tension of the running [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file). You really want to use this:

```bat
"%~dp0…\program.exe"
```

*`…` represents an actual directory sequence, not a relative path*

To get a better idea of what is going on open a Command Prompt window, enter `Call /?` and read its output.

*Note: the `p` in `%~dp0` already has a trailing backslash, so you don't need to append one yourself.*

Comment: using `%~dp0…` I can't use xcopy and replace,
`ΓÇª` this part is somehow added to the path

Comment: You did not take care when reading my answer, specifically, where I used an ellipsis, `…`, 'to represent an actual directory sequence, not a relative path'. If `program.exe` is in the same location as your batch file then use `%~dp0program.exe`, if its relative, _for example in the user profile directory, with the batch on the desktop_, you'd use, `%~dp0..\program.exe`, _(those are two periods)_.

Comment: Thank you again,I actually read it, but I didn't understand it